Unrecognized storage scheme: uc-volumes
I've created a compute cluster by specifying the docker image as databricksruntime/standard:15.4-LTS and Authentication: default.
I have set the spark config as: spark.databricks.unityCatalog.volumes.enabled true.
From an attached notebook, I try to access my Volumes and only see the following:
!ls /dbfs/Volumes

Which returns:

mount.err

!cat /dbfs/Volumes/mount.err

Which returns:

Unrecognized storage scheme: uc-volumes

Any ideas why the compute cluster is unable to mount the volumes?

When working with volumes files on the cluster outside of spark, you can use this syntax to access them:
/Volumes/catalog_name/schema_name/volume_name/path/to/files

so you should be able to ls /Volumes
https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/volumes.html#programmatically-work-with-files-in-volumes-on-databricks
